# How to set the column height in Bootstrap to 100% of the parent height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been tinkering with my code for a while. and I've been having a hard time setting the height of the bootstrap column

> col-xs-4, col-sm-4

To fill 100% of the height of the div's parent.

Here's the **HTML code**

```
<div class="cover">
<div class="cover-text">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
    <h1>Mission</h1>
    <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
</div>              

<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
    <h1>Services</h1>
    <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
    <h1>People</h1>
    <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>      
</div>

</div> <!-- End of row -->
</div> <!-- End of container-fluid -->
</div> <!-- End of cover=-text -->
</div> <!-- End of cover -->
```

Here's the **CSS**

```
html,
body,
.cover {
height: 100%;   
}

.cover {
background: url('../img/couchfriends.jpg') top left no-repeat;
background-size: cover;

display: table;
width: 100%;

/*padding: 10% 20%;*/
box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px #000;
}

.cover-text {
text-align: center;
color: white;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I have tried altering the CSS for the parents of the columns. I have yet to find any answer for this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to use the `flex` css for to set the same height for all the column